# Python: How to control Lineedit input and output in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit, textchanged

The code posted below creates a simple dialog window with only widget: **QLineEdit**.
Typing anything into this field triggers fixText() method (on textChanged) which cleans an incoming string argument. After a string was 'cleaned' the method updates the QLineEdit with the result.

**The goal:** regardless of what user types in to the lineedit field:

The first four letters are always uppercase. 
The fifth character is always underscore.

Remaining characters in a string don't have to be cleaned beyond of what cleanupString() does.

Example of what needs to be achieved: **ABCD_helloWorld**

**A problem encountered:** Unable to insert an underscore character without messing things up.
The lines of the code responsible for insertion of underscore are currently commented...

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui  
class Dialog_01(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow,self).__init__()

        myQWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        myBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()       


        self.myQLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit("Type text here")
        self.myQLineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.fixText)

        myBoxLayout.addWidget(self.myQLineEdit)        

        myQWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(myQWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle('Dialog 01')

    def fixText(self, arg):
        arg=str(arg)
        if not arg: return

        arg=self.cleanupString(arg)

        if len(arg)<3: result=arg.upper()
        else:     result = arg[0:4].upper()+arg[4:]
        # resultList=list(result)
        # resultList.insert(4, '_')
        # result=''.join(resultList)
        self.myQLineEdit.blockSignals(True)
        self.myQLineEdit.setText(result)
        self.myQLineEdit.blockSignals(False)

    def cleanupString(self, line=None):
        if line==None: return
        invalid = invalid = ['!','"','#','$','%','&','\\','(',')','*','+',',','-','.','/'
                    ,':',';','<','=','>','?','@','[',"'",']','^','`','{','|','}','~', ' ']
        for c in invalid: 
            if len(line)>0: line=line.replace(c,'_')
        return line


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog_1 = Dialog_01()
    dialog_1.show()
    dialog_1.resize(480,320)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## FIXED CODE:

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui    

class Dialog_01(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow,self).__init__()

        myQWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        myBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()       


        self.myQLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit("Type text here")
        self.myQLineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.fixText)

        myBoxLayout.addWidget(self.myQLineEdit)        

        myQWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(myQWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle('Dialog 01')

    def fixText(self, arg):
        arg=str(arg)
        if not arg: return

        arg=self.cleanupString(arg)

        if len(arg)<=3: result=arg.upper()
        else:     result = arg[0:4].upper()+"_"+arg[5:]

        self.myQLineEdit.blockSignals(True)
        self.myQLineEdit.setText(result)
        self.myQLineEdit.blockSignals(False)

    def cleanupString(self, line=None):
        if line==None: return
        invalid = invalid = ['!','"','#','$','%','&','\\','(',')','*','+',',','-','.','/'
                    ,':',';','<','=','>','?','@','[',"'",']','^','`','{','|','}','~', ' ']
        for c in invalid: 
            if len(line)>0: line=line.replace(c,'_')
        return line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog_1 = Dialog_01()
    dialog_1.show()
    dialog_1.resize(480,320)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
    if len(arg)<=3: result=arg.upper()
    else: result = arg[0:4].upper()+"_"+arg[5:]
```

Although, you won't be able to use backspace to delete… you will have to select the text to delete it.